# Admin index route ignored w/ CakePHP 2.1

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.1

I'm working on a CakePHP 2.1 project and I have an issue concerning the "homepage" for admin panel.

When I enter : mysite.com/admin
I have a message telling me "AdminController cannot be found".

I declared this route in config/routes.php :

```
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

And when I enter mysite.com/admin/mycontroller as URI, it works.
Do you have an idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Edit | My routes.php file :`

```
/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/View/Pages/home.ctp)...
 */
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';


// Custom routes
Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'jobapplications', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

Comment: There are probably many more routes defined, ie there may be conflicting routes.

Comment: I edited my post with the content of routes.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, there are conflicting routes, namely [**the default routes**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.1.5/lib/Cake/Config/routes.php) provided by the core, which you are including via

```
require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

before defining your `/admin` route.

The defaults connect various routes that can cloak yours, for example:

```
Router::connect("/{$prefix}/:controller", $indexParams);
```

or

```
Router::connect('/:controller', array('action' => 'index'));
```

Long story short, order matters, move your route definition above the inclusion of the default routes.

Comment: If I had known it was as simple as this... I'm totally new to CakePHP so I didn't check default code lines. Thank you !